# The change in gravitational potential energy of a meter stick that swings through the vertical starting at rest from the horizontal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Full question:

[image]

My attempt:

So I tried $KE = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$.

Since this was a meter stick, I calculated $I = \frac{1}{3}mL^2 = \frac{1}{3}(.180 kg)(1m^2) = .006\;kg m^2$

Then I attempted to find $\omega$ by doing $\omega_f^2 = \omega_i^2 + 2\alpha\theta$ and did $\omega_f = \sqrt{2 (9.8) (\frac{\pi}{2})} = 5.54 rad/s$. Now, I calculate kinetic energy by doing,

$KE = \frac{1}{2}(.006\; kgm^2)(5.54 rad/s)^2 = .09207 J$

I figured this was the kinetic energy when the meter stick is in the vertical position of the swing, so then gravitational potential energy gets converted to kinetic energy, thus this should be the answer to a).

However, the answer to this problem is:

[image]

Alternatively, I tried calculating gravitational potential energy to be equal to $mgh$, so $ (.180 kg * 9.8 m/s^2 * 1 m) = 1.764 J$, and subtracting previous result gets 1.67 J, which is still not correct.

I then considered that maybe I'm suppose to use the center of mass as the mass for gravitational potential energy, so I tried (.06)(9.8)(1m) = .588 J, which is still not quite right, so now I am out of ideas.

Comment: Your centre of mass idea is right, but its the full mass 0.180 kg over 0.5 metres. Which is the -0.882J you need.

Comment: Why is it $.5$ metres since the entire meter stick is swinging in a circle of radius 1 m?

Comment: The *end* of the stick ends up 1 m lower.  The centre of mass ends up 0.5 m lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has changed by $-0.882$J. It is $m*g*\Delta h$. $\Delta h$ is calculated from change in center of mass which is $-0.5 mts$ compared to datum level.

Comment: why is the center of mass $-0.5 mts$ and what is $ts$ here?

Comment: Consider the horizontal position COM and the vertical one. The change in height is negative and PE decreases and mts is metres.

Comment: When the meter stick is held out horizontally, the y-coordinate of the center of mass relative to one end of the meter stick is  $1m$ and the x-coordinate is $.5 m$. In the vertical position, the  y center of mass is $.5m$ and x-coordinate of the center of mass is $0m$. Ok, so i can see how the y center of mass changes by .5, then it would (9.8)(.180)(1m) - (9.8)(.180)(.5) = .882 J.  Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Also, why is the velocity 5.42 rad/s and not 5.54 rad/s like I calculated?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates system is perspective based. But remember the height is changed by 0.5 from initial to final, no matter what. So mg*(change in height) is change in PE.